# Is there a function to log data after an importdata() function refreshes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let us say I have an importdata function that refreshes every day and returns a table of 10 rows. Is there a function that allows me to log the data of the cells into another part of the workbook? So theoretically after a couple of weeks, I would have historical data automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Google Apps Script** to copy and paste data to another sheet and create an **Installable Triggers** with event source of **time-driven** that will schedule the execution of script.

### Example:

This script will append data from Sheet1 to Sheet2:

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2 = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sh1.getDataRange().getValues();
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, 1).setValues(data);
}
```

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

This trigger will run the script every 12MN to 1AM everyday.

[image: Setup]

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)